# ProGuard Reading library directory

Tags: android, intellij-idea, proguard

I've been struggling with this one for a while now. I'm trying to `Generate Signed APK` in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3 and **Run ProGuard 4.7** on the APK but I can't get rid of the following error:

> Error: ProGuard: [project_name] Error: Can't read [C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard\libs] (No such file or directory)

The error message is preceded by this message:

> Information: ProGuard: [project_name] Reading library directory [C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard\libs]

There is only a `lib` directory in that location containing `proguard.jar` and the two other jar files. I created an empty `libs` directory but got even more errors after that.

Otherwise the obfuscation seems to work properly, and without the obfuscation the signed APK is generated correctly.

The Android SDK Build-tools version is 20.

**This is the proguard-project file:**

```
-libraryjars libs

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle
{
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable
{
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class *
{
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable
{
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that this problem boils down to the line `-libraryjars libs` in the `proguard-project` file. I managed to properly `Generate Signed APK` with a simple test project when I removed that line from `proguard-project.txt`. However, when `-libraryjars libs` wasn't removed, the obfuscation failed.

If that line is stripped when trying to run ProGuard on the actual project, it gives even more errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, Eric.

Actually, I already solved the problem. Just hadn't updated the answer here until now.

Yes, `-libraryjars` in `proguard-project.txt` was the root of all evil. I just included it there because of some example configurations I came across.

**Here's the properly working configuration:**

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle
{
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable
{
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class *
{
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable
{
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.**
{
   public *;
}

-keep public class com.google.ads.**
{
   public *;
}

-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have -libraryjars or -injars in your configuration. The Android build process (Ant, Eclipse, Gradle, and presumably IntelliJ IDEA as well) internally already specifies those options for you.

I haven't come across the Android SDK adding `-libraryjars` to `proguard-project.txt` (and specified paths are relative to the directory of the configuration file itself, not to `.../tools/proguard`), but maybe you should update to the latest version of the SDK to avoid the problem.